# Current standard of authentification

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, certificate-authority

What is the current standard of authentification?

I thought it is `server` and `client authentification`.

But I typed for e.g. `https://www.google.com/` and checked the packages in wireshark. And there is only a `server authentification`. I am wondering why the `server` is never sending me the `TLS CertificateRequest-message` (Isn't it the only way how `client-authentification` can be accomplished?).

Shouldn't that be standard and why why should a HTTPS-Webserver trust me? 
(Retrieving a certificate from a common CA should be easy for my webbrowser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who said the server *has* to trust you? For many HTTPS sites, a server does the same thing for everyone; Google is happy to do a search for anyone, and nothing it sends you is necessarily even a little bit sensitive from their point of view. If Google doesn't care who you are, there is literally no reason to do client authentication.

If client authentication is desired, you still don't need to do so through TLS. Once you have a secure channel to another party, you can send info along that channel, so once the server has authenticated the client can just authenticate by sending a password. That doesn't work for the server because there are typically many clients, all of whom would need to know the password, and so could impersonate the server to another client. In contrast, it's not as big a problem if the server can impersonate a client, because servers tend to be more trusted than clients (they'll take anyone as a client, the reverse is not true). If the client sends a password, the server must have already authenticated, so that's why that *must* happen in TLS, while client auth doesn't have to happen then.

Lastly, since passwords *do* work OK for client auth and are easier for users to deal with, most sites use them. TLS client certs from CAs have little point in most cases anyways; if pseudonymity is fine you can just have people directly upload a client cert of their choice, if it isn't you normally have a more authoritative issuer than just any commercial CA (i.e. have *one* trusted issuer, which is often just yourself)

Comment: Thanks for meantion passwords and login, acutually i didn't thought about that. May Google was a bad example. So generally in HTTPS communication there is only a server-authentification?

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP, nearly no one uses TLS client authentication. Authentication is done either on the HTTP layer (browser popup asking for user name and password) or on the an even higher layer using login forms. One exception is CAcert, they optionally allow login by certifacte as well as login by password.

Your webbrowser can not just retrieve "a certificate from a common CA". For TLS client authentication to make any sense, the certificate must prove your identity in some way. Typically, when you obtain a client certificate (if you do that at all), you have to prove your identity to some trusted third party, perhaps by showing a government-issued ID card. The trusted third party checks your ID and Google can rely on the fact that you are the user you claim to be. So YOU would have to obtain "a certificate from a (common?) CA", add it as personal certificate to your browser and tell google to associate that certificate with your google account. This is too complicated for mass deployment.

Comment: By common i meant a trusted CA. Sorry for the irretation.